# How to tell if PCIe card is supported in my MacPro?

Tags: ssd, mac-pro

I have a mid-2010 MacPro Tower. Bays are full, including 2nd optical drive slot.
I've seen PCIe cards that will hold 4 M.2 SSD blades, but the specs listed don't list MacOS as supported, although in some cases, a comment from a buyer says it works in a Mac.

Is there a way to tell if a given card will work? [Item](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EHKCMIG) shows "Chipset: Marvell 88SE9230 support HyoperDuo" in case this makes a difference.

Comment: I'd be far more inclined to trust someone like [OWC\(MacSales\)](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/hard-drives/sata/mac-pro) than some random thing on Amazon/eBay which says it supports nix & Win

Comment: It's not so much compatible with the MacPro but rather compatible with macOS.  PCIe is PCie.  Whether there's drivers for it is a different story.  That said, I don't see why it wouldn't work - it should just show up as a drive.

Comment: i would definitely avoid anything that doesn't specifically state it is compatible with a Mac Pro. Most advertisers aren't even aware such a machine exists, it's far too niche for them. Equivalent of buying a non-Mac-flashed GPU... you're fine so long as you don't need to see the display before login...

Comment: I had a Dell Fibre Channel PCIe card in an XServe and it worked flawlessly.  It's unknown if your card will work, but one thing is for certain, it won't damage anything.  If it doesn't work, just remove it and return it.  Amazon is great for returns.

Comment: Lots of good answers or good points to answers here - let's get an answer on record or two rather than use comments for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no comprehensive and easy place to check. Whatever pci card you place in will get power and send data to the rest of the system, but each OS has different drivers included.

The safest bet is for the card vendor to list or provide drivers or compatibility notices for you to know if it works natively without adding a driver on some or all versions of macOS / OS X.

That being said, storage is one of the safer bets since the API/interfaces there are stable for quite some time and PCI is not bleeding edge or likely to be something the vendor didn’t anticipate.

The next safe bet is to buy from a vendor that has clear sales and return policies or can support you before you buy. This usually means paying for that service (or them charging a slightly higher price across the board) since the vendors with the lowest price can just list things and not care if you get what you need since they have to pay someone to know and test things or at least follow up on returns and learn by trial and error what works and what gets returned.